# What kind of bird did I hear at three AM in Germany

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I woke up at three AM from some sort of industrial noise outside. In addition to the noise I heard some creaking like from a stuck door. After the initial noise had ended, something that sounded like birds calling continued for at least 30 minutes.

The most common call sounded like staccato tweeting that lasted for about a second and increased in tone height. This call I heard many times. There were also some slower, non staccato beeps but no continuous singing like you'd hear from a blackbird.

I'm in southern Germany, in a city near a park. The area is brightly lit. It could conceivably be bats, but in my experience they don't tweet loudly and they dont make a staccato noise.

Comment: Try to listen on line a nightingale, maybe it was a far away one and you could hear only the most characteristic notes which are similar to what you describe. Are you south or north of Munich (roughly south of the city there are not breeding nightingale).

Comment: It could be a bird that is normally not out and about at that time, but also disturbed by the industrial noise.

Comment: A bit North of Munich. I think birds decide whether to sing by whether it's light out, so I think it should be a bird or bat that normally sings early, even if the noise woke it up.

Comment: Bats are quite out of question. You would not be able to hear most of their sound, and they definetly wouldn't remotely remind you of a blackbird.

Re: nightingale, try http://www.xeno-canto.org/species/Luscinia-megarhynchos - but I have my doubts.